# Symfony2 install ChillDevProxyTemplatingBundle - Cannot import resource

Tags: symfony, import, resources, bundle

i´ve just installed the ChillDevProxyTemplating Bundle for symfony2, described here:

https://github.com/chilloutdevelopment/ChillDevProxyTemplatingBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/installation.md

My templates was rennamed correctly by the bundle (from 'default' to 'php'), but when i try to call my controller I get the following error:

Cannot import resource "." from (...)app/cache/dev/assetic/routing.yml". (The following loader(s) are not registered: default).

How to fix?

Comment: Got the exact same problem. I suppose the bundle is broken but I can't figure out how to correct it. I sent a request on github for this. Hope we can get help soon.

Answer (score 0):

As explained here: https://github.com/chilloutdevelopment/ChillDevFileManagerBundle/issues/27

You might just need to install ChillDevViewHelpersBundle to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to support of community I was able to investigate this problem:

https://github.com/chilloutdevelopment/ChillDevProxyTemplatingBundle/issues/2

The problem was, that Assetic, in dev environment tries to parse all the templates based on templating engine name so it needs loader for each templating engine - of course for "default" there was no loader and thus caused an exception.